# Why use wake_up_all() and not wake_up_interruptible()?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to understand why `wake_up_all(&lock->queue)` macro is used in the code below, and is this macro `wake_up_interruptible()` is same macro?

Please guide me in this regard, thank you.

```c
void ttm_read_unlock(struct ttm_lock *lock)
{
    spin_lock(&lock->lock);
    if (--lock->rw == 0)
        wake_up_all(&lock->queue);
    spin_unlock(&lock->lock);
}

static bool __ttm_read_lock(struct ttm_lock *lock)
{
    bool locked = false;

      spin_lock(&lock->lock);
      if (unlikely(lock->kill_takers)) 
    {
          send_sig(lock->signal, current, 0);
          spin_unlock(&lock->lock);
        return false;
       }
      if (lock->rw >= 0 && lock->flags == 0) 
    {
            ++lock->rw;
            locked = true;
      }
      spin_unlock(&lock->lock);
      return locked;
}

int ttm_read_lock(struct ttm_lock *lock, bool interruptible)
{
    int ret = 0;

      if (interruptible)
          ret = wait_event_interruptible(lock->queue,__ttm_read_lock(lock));
      else
            wait_event(lock->queue, __ttm_read_lock(lock));
      return ret;
}
```

Comment: If you want to understand how the macro is implemented, then look up its definition in the .h file where it is defined.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Your question now makes no mention of what software you are editing so we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a task waits on a waitqueue in the Linux kernel it can be in either interruptible or uninterruptible wait.  The former will be woken by signals and the latter not.  The type of wait is controlled by the waiting task when it waits on the waitqueue.

The `wake_up_all()` function will wake up every task waiting on the given wait queue, both those waiting interruptibly and uninterruptibly.  This code is using `wake_up_all()` because it supports tasks waiting uninterruptibly for this particular condition (see `ttm_read_lock()`).

The `wake_up_interruptible()` function only wakes tasks waiting interruptibly, so would only be used if you did *not* want to wake tasks in uninterruptible wait.

Comment: You mean to say wake_up_all() will wake up those tasks that are in uninterruptible wait queue , and wake_up_interruptible() marco will wake up those tasks that are not in uninterruptible wait but waiting for interrupts to wake them up ...need some clarification in this.

Comment: @Rajan: `wake_up_all()` wakes up all tasks on the wait queue regardless of whether they're waiting interruptibly or uninterruptibly.  `wake_up_interruptible()` wakes up only those tasks in interruptible wait.

Comment: Also, `wake_up()` and `wake_up_interruptible()` only wake a single task waiting on the queue. There is a `wake_up_interruptible_all()` function to wake up all tasks that are waiting interruptibly on the queue.

Comment: @IanAbbott I believe `wake_up()` wakes up all non-exclusive waiters, and up to one exclusive waiter (same with `wake_up_interruptible()`, but for interruptible tasks). `wake_up_all()` wakes up all waiters including all exclusive waiters.

Comment: @Torin Yes you are correct, and there may also be "priority" waiters that will eat up that one wake up without waking any other waiters. `wake_up_nr(x, nr)` (where `nr` is greater than 0) will wake up to `nr` priority waiters (say, *p* priority waiters), then if `nr`-*p* > 0 will wake all non-exclusive waiters and up to `nr`-*p* exclusive waiters. `wake_up_all(x)` wakes all waiters and `wake_up(x)` is equivalent to `wake_up_nr(x, 1)`.